# xelatex error paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete

Tags: xetex, errors

Hi I ve got this error message

```
Runaway argument?
\x@protect \[\protect \[  \@nil  \@ifpackageloaded {amstex}{\def \@tempa \ETC.
Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete.
<to be read again> \par 
 l.435 \newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
```

while compiling this in XeLaTex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%thesis

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titling}


\begin{document}
bla
\end{document}
```

What seems to be the pbm?

Answer (score 7):

`polyglossia` (or a package it loads) makes `\[` robust but `amsthm` isn't expecting that. If you reset the original definition, things work better,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%thesis


\let\zz\[\let\zzz\]
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\let\[\zz\let\]\zzz


\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
bla
\end{document}
```

(I removed redundant packages from the example)

Comment: David, it works. The original definition of what does the combination of \let\zz\[\let\zzz\] reset?

Comment: @agozar it saves the definition of `\[` in `\zz` and `\]` in `\zzz` (the z names are just arbitrary local names) and then restores them after polyglossia, setting `\[` back to `\zz` which is its original definition, and same for `\]`

Comment: @ggll that isn't a comment anyone can act on. Which packages? Also which format as the situation has changed since this answer, latex now makes `\[` robust by default. Probably best to ask a new question on teh sit ewith a complete example that shows the problem rather than comment on an old answer.

Comment: getting the same error without using polyglossia: solved by loading amsthm after amsmath as advised here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164892/runaway-argument-error-when-using-the-wx-ijcis-class