# 'Runaway argument? ' error when using the wx-ijcis class

Tags: errors, amsthm

I get the following error message when compiling for a journal article:

```
Runaway argument?
\relax \ifmmode \@badmath \else \bgroup \let \eqnnum \relax \let \refstepeqcnt 
\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.435 \newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
```

See the sample code below. The same file with exactly the same packages works properly with any other class (e.g. `article`).

```
\documentclass{ws-ijcis}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
dfdfd
\end{document}
```

The journal class file can be found [here](http://www.worldscientific.com/page/ijcis/stylefiles-readme-2e).

Comment: The AMS packages are not compatible with the class. Neither is the `caption` package, so you should say `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`. Why the class doesn't want to be compatible with `amsmath` is a mystery.

Answer (score 4):

The `ws-ijcis` is not compatible with `amsmath`; it defines its own `equation*` environment. It's not compatible with `amsthm` either, because it defines a `proof` environment.

The weird error is due to the fact that you don't load `amsmath` prior to `amsthm`, so following a branch in a conditional where a wrong assumption is made on `\[` (which is again redefined by the class).

A workaround could be

```
\documentclass{ws-ijcis}

\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} % also caption is incompatible
\begin{document}
dfdfd
\end{document}
```

but I guess the journal copy editors will not be happy with it. Looking at the class you're supposed to use `equation` or `equation*` for one line equations and `eqnarray` or `eqnarray*` for multiline displays (the environment is redefined too).

Comment: my paper has few algorithms as well. ws-ijcis has algorithm environment defined but i am getting no idea on how to use it.

Comment: @user961708 I don't think there should be problems about that.